# I can not find C++ project in Qt designer file->New

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

I try to use Qt4 in Ubuntu,

I downloaded Qt4 by using linux command.

```
Qt Library
$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-core
$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-dbg
$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev 
$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-gui

Qt Designer
$ sudo apt-get install qt4-designer
$ sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools 

Qt IDE
$ sudo apt-get install qtcreator

Compiler
$ sudo apt-get install g++
```

However,
I cannot find the c++ project tab in my environment.
There are only  templates and widets in here.. :( no C++.

/There is no c++ project settings...

What should I do?

Comment: Um, did you try to launch `qtcreator` instead?

Comment: Why Qt4? It was released a decade ago

Comment: I downloaded Qtcreator, but I don't know how to use that one... So I just downloaded QTdesigner which is much comfortable for me.

Comment: No one knows why it happens?                                                                       I tried Qtcreator, but it makes new problem.... It can not get the socket library: QTcpSocket and QTcpServer...

Answer (score 0):

Qt Designer is not an IDE, it's just a user interface template editor.

Qt Creator is the IDE. You'll first have to go to its Settings dialog, into the Build & Run pane, and:

1. Add your version of Qt. Creator can be used with multiple versions, and it won't know about yours unless you specifically tell it where it is.
2. Create a so-called **kit** that bundles the Qt version you've registered with a particular compiler, debugger, and target.